# Occasional java.io.IOException: Operation not permitted only on Android 7.0 by DatagramSocket.send()

Tags: sockets, multicast, datagram, android-7.0-nougat, multicastsocket

The following code works fine virtually 100% time on all Android device Android 7.0:

```
DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
clientSocket.setSoTimeout(4000);
clientSocket.setReuseAddress(true);        
clientSocket.setBroadcast(true);
...
DatagramPacket dpSend = new DatagramPacket(baSendData, baSendData.length, InetAddress.getByName("239.255.255.250"), 3702);
clientSocket.send(dpSend);
```

On Android 7.0, only on Android 7.0, clientSocket.send(dpSend) generates the following error occasionally. I want to emphasize "**occasionally**".  It works fine most of the time.

I am wondering if anyone could offer any insight of Android 7.0 to shed some light on why the exception happens only on Android 7.0.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. I'm not able to reproduce the exception. It only crashes on Android API version 26 and 27. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Having same issues

Comment: Me too having same issue.